# Why is contour sorting the data in the contour matrix C?

Tags: matlab, sorting, contour

I have a function `f(x,y)` and I would like to draw the level curves of `f` with respect to a fixed vector

```
v=(v1,...,vn)  % not sorted
```

using a meshgrid `[X,Y]`.

This can be done using the function `[C,h]=contour(X,Y,f,v)`.

But then, when I want to recover the data of each level curve, I found that `C` has sorted my vector `v` in an increasing way.

I would like to recover `C` in such a way that it keeps my fixed order of `v`.

This can be done using a loop over the components on `v`, one by one, using

```
[Ci,hi]=contour(X,Y,f,[vi,vi])
```

but I have found it inefficient, when taking the number of components of `v` large enough (Lets say, 10000 components).

How can I recover the original unsorted vector `v` from `C`(with the corresponding information given by `C`)?

Comment: Why do you need the order of `C` to correspond to the unsorted vector `v`?

Comment: Because I want to process certain information in a not ordered way (Let us say in this case, the drawings will appear in a not ordered way if I plot one by one the information on C from left to right)

Comment: It is still not very clear what you are trying. And based on your comments on our answers, it seems that we don t understand your question sufficiently. Can you explain the application and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The level curves of the function `f` represent the movement of a particle around a domain. For instance, let us take a unit square. 

So I can calculate the time the particle takes from one side of the square to the other. 

Now, I'm using a certain model for which I would like to calculate these times in a not increasing way, but with respect to the fixed order of the vector `v` instead.

Unfortunately, I don't know another way to do this without `contour` (which basically sorts my vector `v`), and I would really like to keep this special order for the times to make a posterior analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is easiest to sort the contour levels yourself in advance using

```
[w,iv,iw] = unique(v)
```

This will sort your data in v and only keep unique values. `iv` and `iw` are index vectors that allow you to redo the sorting from v --> w on any other data set, because w = v(iv) and v = w(iw).

Now use `w` instead of `v` to plot your contours. You can then use `iw` to 
'unsort' the data in `C`. If necessary, take a look at [Contour Properties > Contour Matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour-properties.html) for the specifications of `C`.

Comment: I am not sure I understood the part of using `iw` to unsort the data in `C`. 

How can I apply `iw` over a data set whose component range varies according with the number of points `contour`takes? 

I suspect that the `contour` function is sorting the vector before presenting the matrix `C`, but I didn't see how could I manipulate the specifications in Contour Properties > Contour Matrix for avoiding this sorting.

Comment: @Ankara You can't avoid that contour sorts your data. But using the index vectors, you could transform C such that it has the same order as your original vector.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the answer to your question is that MATLAB applies `unique` to the contour levels before tracking the contours.

I'm not sure that recovering the unsorted vector is going to be helpful  since there is not necessarily a single contour line/loop at each level.  So in general this contour matrix must be processed in a loop at some point I believe.

Depending on what you intend to do with the contour line data subsequently what I have done in the past may be useful.  (I have basically copied the code verbatim from a function I wrote a while ago.)

This code creates a mask matrix which enables me to extract all the points for each level from the contour matrix:

```
% Create the contours
[c, ch] = contour(X, Y, f, v);

% Create a mask for the contour matrix for each level.
l = numel(v);
n = size(c,2);
cmask = false(l,n);
fCtrNotLoop = false(1,l);
% Don't think this is possible without a loop...
ii = 1;
while ii < n
    m = c(2,ii);
    cmask(v == c(1,ii), ii+1:ii+m) = true;
    % Remove duplicate point of loops.
    if all(c(:,ii+1)==c(:,ii+m))
        cmask(v == c(1,ii), ii+m) = false;
    else
        fCtrNotLoop(lvls == c(1,ii)) = true;
    end
    ii = ii + m + 1;
end
```

(You may or may not want to remove duplicate points that close loops -- I needed to for my application.)

Then to get the points in the contour(s) at level `v(jj)` use something like:

```
pts = c(:,cmask(jj,:));
```

With a slight modification you could use `cmask` to reorder your contour matrix: change `ii+1:ii+m` in the `cmask(...) = true` line to `ii:ii+m` and  remove the duplicate points `if` statement.  Then loop through each level to populate a copy of `c`:

```
% WARNING: Untested code follows!
cnew = c;
kk = 1;
for jj = 1 : l
    s = sum(cmask(jj, :));
    cnew(:, kk:kk+s-1) = c(:, cmask(jj, :));
    kk = kk + s;
end
```

As `cmask` has dimensions `[length(v),length(c)]` if you have a huge number of levels and lots of contour points in each then memory consumption may become a problem and modification of this extraction/reordering method may be required - i.e. process each level separately which of course will be slower.

Comment: The problem is that indeed I do have a lot of contour points and levels. Is there any chance I can modify the Contour function itself? I suspect that MATLAB makes the sort inside before presenting the matrix C.

Comment: No I don't think `contour` can be modified. If you have so many contours and such a fine grid aren't you basically plotting an intensity chart? It may be that you would be better to do image processing.